# How to build and internally distribute app for testing before the ad-hoc testing phase?

Tags: ios

I've read the Apple documentation and several posting on here but am still confused about this.

Using a distribution profile and ad-hoc testing is described as being for use when the app is completed, but how should the app be built and distributed to testers while it is still in the development phase?

I have a development profile containing a dev certificate and several devices. How should the testers in possession of the devices in the profile install the app in order to test it?

Comment: www.testflightapp.com : it's brilliant

Comment: You should make that the answer so we can all upvote it. testflightapp is... I'm just repeating you now aren't I?

Comment: Thanks testflightapp might be brilliant but their website is not, after several minutes browsing I still am non the wiser as to what they or their product does. I have a short attention span so have got fed up trying to find out.At the moment there is only one tester, as mentioned I get the impression testflightapp would be overkill at this stage when there's only one tester and the app has only just started and is nowhere near beta stage.  I found this doc: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/DistApps/DistApps.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ad hoc distribution is the way to go for testing on multiple devices. It doesn't matter if the app is already finished or not, the process is the same. Websites like [testflightapp.com](http://testflightapp.com) or [hockeyapp.net](http://hockeyapp.net) can help with distribution to your testers and bug reporting.